# How to print binary table column as zeros and ones using SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with a column of type "binary". When I select this column I see the data automatically converted and printed as a string, for example "    ¢ZêZ". I want to write the select statement in a way that it is printed as actual zeros and ones e.g. "01001010". Note, I am running this query through a python script and dumping the results to a csv file.

If anybody has an idea how to do this your help would be really appreciate it.

Comment: The SQL "binary" type just means "raw bytes".  It doesn't know anything about number bases.  If you want stuff printed with binary digits, then you'll have to do that in your Python code.

Comment: Are there no SQL function that can convert the bytes to zeros and ones format?

Comment: No, because it's just not useful.  SQL is about storing and fetching data, not formatting and presenting data.  It's easy in Python, do it there.

Comment: some formatting can be done using CONVERT() for example. But maybe nothing for binary format.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it at least on my vertica DB.

```
TO_BITSTRING(expression)
```

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/TO_BITSTRING.htm